# how to implement delete functionality from the iphone photo library?

Tags: iphone

I am implementing photo galary.now i want to implement delete photo functionality(animation) from the gallery same as default delete functionality in the iphone photo library.So please advice me.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the "suck" animation is a private animation, and therefore not publicly available in the SDK. You'll have to create your own animation using Core Animation. There should be some examples on Google.